# How to implement transition between two PageRow in leanback BrowseFragment?

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm using a leanback BrowseFragment to implement a simple android tv app. I have two PageRows which are backed by custom fragments. When I switch between the two in the browse navigation area, the content side of the screen goes blank briefly before the new fragment's views appear. How can I fade from one view to the other without a delay in between?

I see some references to "entrance transition" in the docs which I think is what I need, but I can't find any examples of what to do in those callbacks.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.MainFragmentAdapter.html#setEntranceTransitionState(boolean)

---

I tried to implement `setEntranceTransitionState` on my PageRow Fragment's MainFragmentAdapter, but it is never invoked:

```
class GuideFragment: Fragment(), BrowseFragment.MainFragmentAdapterProvider {
    val fragmentAdapter = object: BrowseFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<GuideFragment>(this) {
        override fun setEntranceTransitionState(state: Boolean) {
            Log.v("TEST", "setEntrance($state)")
            fragment.setEntranceTransitionState(state)
        }
    }
    override fun getMainFragmentAdapter() = fragmentAdapter
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this [BrowseFragment.BrowseTransitionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.BrowseTransitionListener.html) class which is a `listener` for transitions between browse headers and rows. Here's an [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/7350fc4/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.java) using `setEntranceTransitionState`.

Comment: Thanks, but BrowseTransitionListener is for transitions where the navigations headers are shown and hidden. I'm looking for transitions when switching between headers while they're still shown on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this when using BrowseSupportFragment.

If you look at the implementation of `swapToMainFragment()`, you'll see that while scrolling the content is set to an empty fragment. When `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` is reached, a regular fragment transaction is used to replace the child fragment with the new content.

Answer (score 0):

leanback has a lot of limitations, It is better to fork the official code and create your own repo and modify it; we did the same in our app.